# Why doesn't closeWhenOpened work on slidable?

Tags: flutter

I want to use closeWhenOpened on a slidable, I set closeWhenOpened to true, but I can have multiple slides, I want only one slide to work, but it doesn't work.

Below is my code,

```
class _mapButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const _mapButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.mapData,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final MapData mapData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: TCard(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
            closeWhenOpened: true,
            closeWhenTapped: true,
            child: Slidable(
              closeOnScroll: false,
              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                children: [
                  SlidableAction(
                    icon: Icons.delete_outline,
                    label: "삭제",
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: (context) {
                      print(mapData.id);
                    },
                  ),
                  SlidableAction(
                    icon: Icons.delete_outline,
                    label: "수정",
                    backgroundColor: TColor.backColor,
                    onPressed: (context) {
                      print(mapData.id);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("클릭");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "data",
                          style: TText.style.titleLarge,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                          "data",
                          style: TText.style.titleSmall,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

on slideable

```
SlideableAutoCloseBehavior(
            closeWhenOpened: true,
            closeWhenTapped: true,
```

, but it will have 2 slides, can you only have one slide?, why
closeWhenOpened: true,

Doesn't this work?

I'm using flutter_slidable : ^1.3.0 , as the version is updated, I don't know if the usage has changed or if I'm using it wrong, can you give me some advice?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solution is to wrap **all**  `Slidable` in the screen inside single `SlidableAutoCloseBehavior`. Wrapping each `Slidable` with its own `SlidableAutoCloseBehavior` is just an incorrect use of the widget.

1 `SlidableAutoCloseBehavior` widget for 1 group of `Slidable` widgets

Widget tree example:

```
SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
   child: ListView(
      children: [
        Slidable(...), 
        Slidable(...), 
        Slidable(...), 
      ],
    ), 
)
```

I hope it will be helpful for someone.